# Fetching particular value from entity in GAE DataStore without PersistantManager

Tags: java, google-app-engine, validation, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to register a user and allow him to login with userName and Password. My dataStore entity "Racer" contains Name, UserName, Password, Age, BikeModel, City. Key is generated by the application.

I want to validate user. I used query with addFilter() to get the entire details of a particular user. I am struck with getting a particular property of a particular user from the entity in dataStore, say, Password and UserName of a particular user from "Racer".

Over the web, whichever example i got, it was using PersistentManager. I don't want to use it. I don't find any query to fetch details other than Filter and Sort. Please suggest me how to proceed.

Servlet:

```
  public class StoreInDataStore extends HttpServlet {
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    //Getting SignUp form values
        String name=req.getParameter("name1");
     String uname=req.getParameter("uname1");
     String pswd=req.getParameter("pswd1");
     String age=req.getParameter("age");
     String city=req.getParameter("city");
     String bike=req.getParameter("bike");

    //Getting login form values
     String lname=req.getParameter("name");
     String lpswd=req.getParameter("pswd");

     //Creating dataStore
     DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

     //Creating entity
     Entity e=new Entity("Racer");

     //Entering details in racer
     e.setProperty("Name", name);
     e.setProperty("UserName", uname);
         e.setProperty("Password", pswd);
     e.setProperty("Age", age);
     e.setProperty("City", city);
     e.setProperty("Bike Model", bike);

    //Storing in DataStore  
        ds.put(e);      

            //Getting entire details

        Query q=new Query("Racer");
    q.setFilter(FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("UserName", uname));/* UserName takes only the currently entered value(uname). Doesnot fetch from dataStore */
    PreparedQuery pq=ds.prepare(q);
    List<Entity> result = ds.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());

    System.out.println(result);     

}
```

Comment: I hope you do not store passwords as Strings. You should encrypt and salt passwords.

Comment: Yeah, i didnt encrypt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
List<Entity> result = ds.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
```

use

```
Entity result = ds.prepare(q).asSingleEntity();
String password = result.getProperty("Password");
```

Comment: Thank you! This retrieved the password.